# Optimizing searches of a BIG .csv file

Tags: python, regex, optimization, csv

I'm writing a Python script that will take strings from a .csv file and cut them in a specific manner ("cut after R and K when not followed by P"), allow for missing up to two cleavage sites and write the resulting strings to a new .csv file. This works like a charm, but...

Then I need to take *each and every one* of these strings and search through another .csv file (with around 725000 entries) and see if the strings are listed in the big file. If they are, they are to be written to a separate file. I have successfully done this (see code below), but it is SUPER slow... I cut off the big file to around 2000 entries instead of 725000, and it took 15 seconds (meaning around 90 minutes for the whole file). This is way too slow! How can I decrease this computing time?

```py
import csv
import re
import time

# Input should be a .csv file with 2 columns (PrEST ID, PrEST Sequence)
in_file = open('Tryptic Sequences Input.csv','r')
in_file1 = open('Reference Peptides (ENSG, Björn) TEST.csv','r')
out_file = open('Tryptic Sequences Output.csv','w+')
out_file1 = open('Tryptic Sequences Output (non-unique peptides).csv','w+')

# Reader/Writer iterables
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
reader1 = csv.reader(in_file1)
in_list = list(reader)
in_list1 = list(reader1)
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
writer1 = csv.writer(out_file1)
headers = ('PrEST','Peptide')
writer.writerow(headers)
writer1.writerow(headers)

# Initiate variables
Peptide_list = [] # List for Peptides (resets for each PrEST)
ID_list = [] # List for PrEST IDs (resets for each PrEST)
Copy_list = [] # List for non-unique tryptic peptides
Copy_ID_list = []
Peptide = '' # Current peptide (no missed cleavages)
Peptide_MC1 = '' # Current peptide with 1 missed cleavage
Peptide_MC2 = '' # Current peptide with 2 missed cleavages
MC1 = 'N'
MC2 = 'N'
Unique = 'Y'

t0 = time.clock()

# ------ Main PrEST for-loop -------
for row in range(len(in_list)): # For every PrEST (row)
    First = 'Y'
    PrEST_seq = in_list[row][1]

    # -------- Main AA-reader for-loop --------
    for n in range(len(PrEST_seq)): # For every AA in every PrEST

        if ((PrEST_seq[n:n+1] == 'R' or
             PrEST_seq[n:n+1] == 'K') and
             PrEST_seq[n+1:n+2] != 'P'):
            if First != 'Y': # Does not count first peptide + MCs (part of ABP)
                Peptide += PrEST_seq[n:n+1]
                if len(Peptide) >= 6: # Only appends peptide if longer than 6 AA

 # KEY PART ---------------------------------------------------------------------

                    # Searches for non-unique peptides from in_file1
                    for line in range(len(in_list1)):
                        if re.search(r"\b(?=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % Peptide,in_list1[line][2]) != None:
                            Unique = 'N'
                            Copy_ID_list.append(in_list[row][0])
                            Copy_list.append(Peptide)
                            break
                    if Unique == 'Y':
                        ID_list.append(in_list[row][0])
                        Peptide_list.append(Peptide)

 # (repeated twice below) --------------------------------------------------------

                Unique = 'Y' # Resets variable

                # -------- One missed cleavage while-loop --------
                Peptide_MC1 = Peptide
                m = n
                while MC1 == 'N' and m+1 <= len(PrEST_seq):
                    m += 1
                    if ((PrEST_seq[m:m+1] == 'R' or
                         PrEST_seq[m:m+1] == 'K') and
                         PrEST_seq[m+1:m+2] != 'P'):
                        Peptide_MC1 += PrEST_seq[m:m+1]
                        if len(Peptide_MC1) >= 6:

                            for line in range(len(in_list1)):
                                if re.search(r"\b(?=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % Peptide_MC1,in_list1[line][2]) != None:
                                    Unique = 'N'
                                    Copy_ID_list.append(in_list[row][0])
                                    Copy_list.append(Peptide_MC1)
                                    break
                            if Unique == 'Y':
                                ID_list.append(in_list[row][0])
                                Peptide_list.append(Peptide_MC1)
                        Unique = 'Y'
                        MC1 = 'Y'
                    else:
                        Peptide_MC1 += PrEST_seq[m:m+1]
                    # ------------- End MC1 while-loop ------------

                # -------- Two missed cleavages while-loop --------
                Peptide_MC2 = Peptide_MC1
                k = m
                while MC2 == 'N' and k+1 <= len(PrEST_seq):
                    k += 1
                    if ((PrEST_seq[k:k+1] == 'R' or
                         PrEST_seq[k:k+1] == 'K') and
                         PrEST_seq[k+1:k+2] != 'P'):
                        Peptide_MC2 += PrEST_seq[k:k+1]
                        if len(Peptide_MC2) >= 6:

                            for line in range(len(in_list1)):
                                if re.search(r"\b(?=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % Peptide_MC2,in_list1[line][2]) != None:
                                    Unique = 'N'
                                    Copy_ID_list.append(in_list[row][0])
                                    Copy_list.append(Peptide_MC2)
                                    break
                            if Unique == 'Y':
                                ID_list.append(in_list[row][0])
                                Peptide_list.append(Peptide_MC2)
                        Unique = 'Y'
                        MC2 = 'Y'
                    else:
                        Peptide_MC2 += PrEST_seq[k:k+1]
                    # ------------ End MC2 while-loop -------------

                # Resets variables
                Peptide = ''
                Peptide_MC1 = ''
                Peptide_MC2 = ''
                MC1 = 'N'
                MC2 = 'N'
            elif First == 'Y': # Doesn't count first cleavage (contains ABP)
                Peptide = ''
                First = 'N'
        else: # Non-cleavable AAs - Peptide grows
            Peptide += PrEST_seq[n:n+1]

        # ------- End main AA-reader for-loop --------

    Peptide_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True) # Sorts list by length
    for j in range(len(Peptide_list)): # Writes current PrEST to file
        Collected_list = (ID_list[j],Peptide_list[j])
        writer.writerow(Collected_list)
    Peptide_list = []
    ID_list = []

    Copy_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    for j in range(len(Copy_list)):
        Collected_list = (Copy_ID_list[j],Copy_list[j])
        writer1.writerow(Collected_list)
    Copy_list = []
    Copy_ID_list = []

    # ----- End main PrEST-reader for-loop -----      
print('------- Finished -------')
print('Total time',time.clock()-t0,'seconds')
out_file.close()
out_file1.close()
```

I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general, and I'm quite certain that my code is lacking in number of ways. It's quite fast if I don't include the searching of the big .csv file, but I kind of need that part. I don't know if it could be faster just in the searching part(s), or it could be faster in other places as well.

Comment: Have you considered using a database like [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)?

Comment: [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place for this type of question, but I'm not sure where the border between "what is wrong with this code" and "how can I make this code better" is.

Comment: Give up regexp and reiterating all string from first file every time. Get them into set/dictionary, and find them through a simple query.

Comment: I tried using a dictionary, and that did the trick - down to 1.5 minutes instead of 90. Thanks alot!